# How can I check if a string contains a special letter?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am building a program that gets a password as a string and checks its strength by a couple of factors. I want to check if the entered string contains a special character (like %,$,# etc.) but so far I couldn't able to figure it out. What is the best way to do so?

Edit: I am not searching for a specific character. I need to search the string to find if it has some kind of a non-letter, non-digit character.

Edit 2 : I want to do it without a loop.

Answer (score 5):

You can possibly use regex!

```
>>> import re
>>> s='Hello123#'
>>> re.findall('[^A-Za-z0-9]',s)
['#']
>>> if re.findall('[^A-Za-z0-9]',s):print True
... 
True
```

Happy Coding!

Hope it helps!

Comment: Prints True for s = '2.7.5'

Answer (score 1):

As you stated you don't want to use a loop, and probably never worked with regexes, how about a list comprehension?

```
import string

all_normal_characters = string.ascii_letters + string.digits

def is_special(character):
  return character not in all_normal_characters

special_characters = [character for character in password if is_special(character)]
```

Let me know if this works, or if you need more help!

Answer (score -2):

You will have to put his into a for loop to check for special character and I think you need to make a list with them all in and then test it like that but this is the basic code you need! Replace the print bit with whatever else you need to do!

```
password = "VerySecurePassw0rd"
if "%" in password:
    print( "Your Password has a special character in it!")

if "%" not in password:
    print ("Your Password does not have a special character in it!")
```

**EDIT:**

Or you could use "else" above

Without using a loop I'm not sure however you could use "elif" but it's not very efficient

```
password = "VerySecurePassw0rd"

if "%" in password:
    print ("Your Password has a special character in it!")
elif "$" in password:
    print( "Your Password has a special character in it!")
elif "#" in password:
    print ("Your Password has a special character in it!")
```

You could also try this:

```
if "%" and "$" in password:
    print("Your Password has a 2 special characters in it!")
```

I think that should work

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I am searching for a way to do this without a loop. Do you have anything in your mind?